# Security and arbitrary code execution inside `.pth` files

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, sys.path

Reading deeply through the [Python `site.py` documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/site.html), I found this regarding `.pth` files:

> Blank lines and lines beginning with # are skipped. Lines starting with import (followed by space or tab) are executed.

These two sentences are easy to miss. They're at the end of a long-ish paragraph, meaning that scanning eyes will easily overlook them. I missed them even when I was actively looking for them.

An example of code execution comes from `python3.6/site-packages/virtualenvwrapper-4.8.2-py2.7-nspkg.pth`:

> ```
> import sys, types, os;has_mfs = sys.version_info > (3, 5);p = os.path.join(sys._getframe(1).f_locals['sitedir'], *('virtualenvwrapper',));importlib = has_mfs and __import__('importlib.util');has_mfs and __import__('importlib.machinery');m = has_mfs and sys.modules.setdefault('virtualenvwrapper', importlib.util.module_from_spec(importlib.machinery.PathFinder.find_spec('virtualenvwrapper', [os.path.dirname(p)])));m = m or sys.modules.setdefault('virtualenvwrapper', types.ModuleType('virtualenvwrapper'));mp = (m or []) and m.__dict__.setdefault('__path__',[]);(p not in mp) and mp.append(p)
> ```

What is the purpose of allowing arbitrary code execution inside `.pth` files?

What are the best practices regarding inspecting or securing `.pth` files given that arbitrary code execution can have wide-ranging negative effects?

Answer (score 2):

> What is the purpose of allowing arbitrary code execution inside .pth files?

It allows packages to configure `sys.path` by using code. This might be used for   conditional branching, e.g. platform-specific customizations.

> What are the best practices regarding inspecting or securing .pth files given that arbitrary code execution can have wide-ranging negative effects?

The same as always - know what you're installing.  Using `pip install somepackage` is already allowing arbitrary code execution, `setup.py` is executed as code. So there is not really any additional vulnerability or possibility to hide code inside a `.pth` file.

There has been discussion recently about the possibility to deprecate and remove `.pth` hacks going forward (Python 3.8+), see [issue33944](https://bugs.python.org/issue33944) for further detail.

Comment: There are also some rare uses of `.pth` files to change the behavior of the interpreter without modifying an application. I'm thinking of [coverage's docs on subprocess coverage](https://coverage.readthedocs.io/en/v4.5.x/subprocess.html#configuring-python-for-sub-process-coverage).

Comment: Yes, `coverage.py` uses it to "get in first", before any user code. Also some naughty installers such as `ruamel.yaml` use .pth files to hack namespace packages back into Python 2. It seems a lot of people are abusing the code execution feature for reasons other than the intended use case (i.e. configuring `sys.path`), but that's always been the case in Python - nothing is prohibited, all consenting adults, etc